# How do I shift this navigation item title to the left?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have this header which is currently centered. And my goal is to shift it to the left so that it sits in the view to the right of the right margin of the back arrow.

Ultimately, the view below gets set in the `titleView` of a `UINavigationBar`

Code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
class GroupMessageTitleView: UIControl {

    struct Constants {
        static let imageSize = CGSize(width: 36.0, height: 36.0)
        static let spacingBetweenImageAndText: CGFloat = 8.0
        static let viewHeight: CGFloat = 40.0
    }

    // MARK: - Views

    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: Constants.imageSize)
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = Constants.imageSize.height / 2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        return imageView
    }()

    private let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = Styleguide.Fonts.pingFangMedium.font(ofSize: 16)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        return label
    }()

    private let subtitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.from(rgb: 0xCDCDCD)
        label.font = Styleguide.Fonts.pingFangMedium.font(ofSize: 14)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, subtitleLabel])
        stackView.spacing = -4.0
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        return stackView
    }()

    private lazy var horizontalStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, self.stackView])
        stackView.spacing = Constants.spacingBetweenImageAndText
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return stackView
    }()

    // MARK: - Properties

    weak var delegate: GroupMessageTitleViewDelegate?

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isHighlighted != oldValue { highlightStateDidChange() }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initializers

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        let initialFrame: CGRect

        if #available(iOS 11.1, *) {
            initialFrame = .zero
        } else {
            // Arbitrary Non Zero Frame. To please the Apple Gods.
            // When the frame is set to .zero on iOS 10,
            // No matter what we do in specfying a size in
            // sizeThatFits or intrinsicContentSize, the frame is not updated
            // Once it's non zero, the frame is then set correctly
            // using sizeThatFits for the size
            initialFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: Constants.viewHeight)
        }

        super.init(frame: initialFrame)

        addSubview(horizontalStackView)

        addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)

        setupConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - View Configuration

    func configure(with presentable: GroupMessageTitlePresentable) {
        titleLabel.text = presentable.name

        let members = "member".pluralize(withCount: presentable.memberCount).localize()
        subtitleLabel.text = "\(presentable.memberCount) \(members)"

        imageView.setImage(with: presentable.imageUrl, fallbackText: presentable.name, fallbackImageSize: Constants.imageSize.height)
    }

    func highlightStateDidChange() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
            self.alpha = self.isHighlighted ? 0.5 : 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Layout

    func setupConstraints() {
        constrain(horizontalStackView) { view in
            // to ensure it is correctly centered, we offset by half the width of the imageView
            let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: Constants.imageSize.width / 2)
            view.edges == inset(view.superview!.edges, insets)
        }

        constrain(imageView) { view in
            view.width == Constants.imageSize.width
            view.height == Constants.imageSize.height ~ .required
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Sizing Methods

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        if #available(iOS 11.1, *) {
            return super.sizeThatFits(size)
        } else {
            // Image Width + Spacing + Title Label Width + Trailing inset
            let width = Constants.imageSize.width + Constants.spacingBetweenImageAndText + self.titleLabel.sizeThatFits(size).width + (Constants.imageSize.width / 2)
            return CGSize(width: width, height: Constants.viewHeight)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Touch Handling

    @objc func handleTap() {
        delegate?.didTap(titleView: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it need to be the title view? You could make it a bar button item, and insert it after the back button.

Comment: Let me give that a try and report back. Thx